# How do I help Visual Studio find the new EnableNonClientDpiScaling() function?

Tags: sdk, windows-10, highdpi

I've updated my SDK to the Win10 Anniversary Edition and still it won't compile. Has this functionality not been released yet? Google just gives me the announcement of the function being available now, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EnableNonClientDpiScaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748621(v=vs.85).aspx) function is declared in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\um\WinUser.h"` the following:

```
WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
EnableNonClientDpiScaling(
    _In_ HWND hwnd);
```

In the options of your project, set the `Target Platform Version` to `10.0.14393.0`

[image]

you'll we able to compile the code when you include the winsuer.h in your solution and call EnableNonClientDpiScaling.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the last step of changing the target platform!